# Why is capybara not available in request specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Working on a new Rails 3.2.9 app with rspec and capybara.

I have the following in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'capybara'
```

and the following in spec/spec_helper.rb:

```
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
```

and in spec/requests/asdf_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe 'Asdf' do
  describe "GET /asdfs" do
    it "should list asdfs" do
      visit asdfs_path
    end
  end
end
```

This test is failing:

```
Failure/Error: visit asdfs_path
NoMethodError:
 undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_2::Nested_1:0x007fa7b68961a0>
# ./spec/requests/asdfs_spec.rb:19:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So it looks like Capybara isn't getting loaded. Ack, why not? I feel like I've done this exact same thing a dozen times before... probably blanking on something stupid.

Comment: Are you using Capybara 2.0?

Comment: Yes I was! My google-search-fu was weak.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So it was a capybara version 2 change. I found this:

http://alindeman.github.com/2012/11/11/rspec-rails-and-capybara-2.0-what-you-need-to-know.html

which explains:

> Upon upgrading to capybara 2.0, ***capybara will not be available by
>   default*** in RSpec request specs. Instead, a new type of spec--the
>   feature spec--has been created for use with capybara.
>
> To upgrade to capybara 2.0, you'll need to do a few things:
>
> - Upgrade rspec-rails to 2.12.0 or greater
> - Move any tests that use capybara from spec/requests to spec/features. Capybara 
>     tests use the visit method and usually assert against page.

Comment: In the interim before you move your feature tests over to **spec/features** from **spec/requests**, you can get your suite passing again by tagging them with `type: :feature`.

Comment: Capybara 1.1.2 also provided some matchers that were quite useful in request specs (e.g. have_selector), which are no longer available unless you convert your request specs to feature specs.

Comment: This link now leads to a 404. Here is the page as redirected from the github page, on archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20160311025041/http://www.andylindeman.com/rspec-rails-and-capybara-2.0-what-you-need-to-know/

Answer (score 4):

Just some additional info for anybody having the same problem with the Capybara upgrade to `2.x`. Check out rspec-rails docs under the [Upgrading to Capybara 2](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/file/Capybara.md) section.

Basically, In order to use the Capybara DSL(page & visit) you must move your existing specs into the `spec/features` directory. So you can only use `page & visit` in acceptance tests. No more page & visit in controller and request specs. Only the rack-test DSL `(get|post|put|delete|head/response.body)` is allowed in controller and request specs.

This is **not** recommended but there is a way to keep your specs working as they are:

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include Capybara::DSL, :example_group => {
    :file_path => "spec/requests"
  }
end
```

The docs state that if you go this route then you are overriding the intended behavior and you are taking a risk.

And definitely don't make this as a reason not to upgrade to `Capybara 2.x`. Feature specs are easy to get used to and are easy to read. `feature` is just an alias for `describe`, `background` is an alias for `before`, `scenario` for `it`, and `given` for `let`.

Hope this helps anyone confused by the new changes.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because it is considered a better default to write tests which only concern one area of interest.
Also sometimes it can be a little bit of a hustle to create the right type of request only to render a view.

Yet there might be cases where view specs are too isolated, since they mock all the controller logic. That might for example be the case when you are testing authorization dependent behavior.

---

#### Using Capybara matchers in request specs

The easiest way to use them, is to explicitly include the required matchers for request specs:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::RSpecMatchers, type: :request
end
```

As taken from [here](https://til-engineering.nulogy.com/Add-have-selector-matcher-to-RSpec-Request-Specs/)

Answer (score -3):

The issue is in capybara gem itself.

`gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'`  solves this issue ( Version 2.0.x fails )

Comment: Yeah, it was a version 2.x issue. But come on, the answer isn't to downgrade. :)